# Why this pattern of wrapping javascript

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

I've seen this pattern of javascript code in several places. 
Can anyone provide me with a good explanation? Thanks in advance!

```
var someVar;
(function(someVar){
    someVar.foo = 'bar';
    //...
})(someVar || (someVar={});
```

Comment: I was especially concerned about `(someVar || (someVar={})`

Comment: This looks like a simple default value.

Comment: `someVar || (someVar={}` may as well be `someVar || {}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [javascript module pattern.](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html) Effectively you are creating a encapsulation in which you can store functions (public,private), variables, other modules. With this pattern, you do not contaminate global. It can be used to simulate to java's packages, .NET namespaces.

For example, I have divided my project to following namespaces using this pattern.

- ProjectName
- ProjectName.helpers
- ProjectName.services
- ProjectName.events

Every namespace has its own functions, therefore they do not mix. I can use same function name in different namespaces. You can write private functions, which are usable only from same module, that is unreachable from public. This is one of the ways to add object oriented principles to javascript.